# How can I print Python's help page straight to stdout?

Tags: python, unix, stdout

I'm trying to write a Unix script that will let me print the Python help page for a given module. My code so far is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if sys.argv[1].endswith(".py"):
        __import__(sys.argv[1][:-3])
        help(sys.argv[1][:-3])
    else:
        __import__(sys.argv[1])
        help(sys.argv[1])
```

It works almost as I want-- Invoking it on a module pulls up the help page in a buffer similar to invoking `less`. (In other words, `help` works exactly as it does when using it in the interpreter.)

What I would like is to get rid of the buffer and print straight to the stdout so that I can use the command with other Unix commands. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: Is the `pydoc` command what you're trying to re-implement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import pydoc

import math # test
print(pydoc.render_doc(math))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
import pydoc

pydoc.help(xrange)
```

Or if you want it in string format

```
pydoc.getdoc(xrange)
```

Comment: For some reason, pydoc.getdoc(module) doesn't work exactly. I get the output:
`str(object) -> string

Return a nice string representation of the object.
If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.` Instead of the documentation for the module.

Comment: `pydoc.getdoc()` would take a reference to a module, not a string containing the name of a module. If you pass it a string, you will get the help for the `str` class.